# Querying SQL with a column being a Map[Int, Int]

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am working on some scala query generator.

One of my column is `Map[Int, Int]`

What would a sql query look like to query on the value of one of the pair?

Something like:

```
WHERE Map[KEY] >= VALUE
```

How to you access one value on a Map in a column in SQL ?

The syntax can be using Postgresql or Athena. If I know the name of the query I can always google the alternatives.

Thanks.

Comment: @jarlh I updated my question. Athena or Postgresql would be great

Comment: Postgres has no "map" datatype, but if the column is a a `json` or `jsonb`, you can use `where (the_column ->> 'key')::int >= 42`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/maps.html

You can go to aws athena and run:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT MAP(
    ARRAY['first', 'last', 'age'],
    ARRAY['Bob', 'Smith', '35']
  ) AS user UNION ALL
  SELECT MAP(
    ARRAY['first', 'last', 'age'],
    ARRAY['john', 'doe', '12']
  ) AS user
)
SELECT user FROM dataset WHERE CAST(user['age'] AS bigint) > 20
```

So the answer was what I asked in my example ! haha

```
WHERE map[key] <operator> <value>
```

---

Also if you are doing :

```
SELECT user FROM dataset WHERE CAST(user['test'] AS bigint) > 20
```

And the key `test` does not exist, this will return 0 row.